# Telethon verions 1.11.3 with python 3.7.3 not seems to be working

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

### Upon trying following code on Telethon 1.11.3 , python 3.7.3

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = xxx #i give my id
api_hash = xxx##i give my 
client = TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():

    # Now you can use all client methods listed below, like for example...
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello to myself!')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I get error as RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not the code itself but the shell you used. IPython and similar run the `asyncio` event loop which break Telethon's `sync` magic.

To work around this, you can use a normal `python` shell or write `async` and `await` in the right places:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = ...
api_hash = ...
client = TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # Now you can use all client methods listed below, like for example...
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello to myself!')

# Note the async and await keywords
async with client:
    await main()
```

Of course, in this scenario, `main()` is not really necessary either:

```py
async with client:
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello to myself!')
```

Comment: Good catch! Some more clarification: IPython runs the `asyncio` event loop for you, so that you can type `await`, `async with` and `async for` directly in the interpreter and it will all Just Work.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer, but i still get following error:SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function. I tried this both on IPython and normal script

Comment: I wanted to edit above comments. It seems to be working on Ipython script. But when i try to run it as part of normal code i get, this: SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create an object for TelegramClient()
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

async with client :
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello!!!!!')
client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized() :
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter verification code : '))
```